# Assigning Unique ID for each Client during Setup

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, service

I'm trying to build a .Net Windows App or Service.  I would like to create a Setup project using Visual Studio Setup template.  When somebody installs this app or service on their machine, I want a Unique ID generated during / after installation and store it permanently somewhere (may be registry).

If I reinstall it should not re-generate the Unique ID because I might be releasing future versions.  I need that ID to be readable by app / service to use that ID to communicate with Server.

What is the best way to generate this unique id per machine?

Comment: As an option you can create Custom Action for your setup project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option you can create [Custom Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d9k65z2d(v=vs.100).aspx) for your setup project.

- Create a class library project and add an [Installer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer(v=vs.110).aspx) from Add New Item window.
- Override Install, Commit, Rollback and Uninstall or related before and after methods.
- Use registry to store the key you need. In install method, Check if the specific registry key not exists then create it for example `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\YourSofteare` create a string key and name it ClientId and generate a unique id like GUID and store it in registry. If the key exists, don't touch it.
- You can use this key in your program, simply read this key from registry at startup of your program.

I've used such custom action to do custom actions during installation.